# Customer can edit the shipping address during checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

How to Customer can able to edit the shipping address during the checkout in Magento 2?

Comment: only when the customer has two address otherwise he cannot edit the default during the checkout but can edit on My account page

Comment: yes, but if customer have multiple address then the customer can able to edit the shipping addres during checkout, is there any possible way?